# "gitolite setup -pk banruosheng.pub" failed when I install it on centos 5.4 32

Tags: centos, gitolite

when I　installed gitolite on my centos 5.4 ,I just found errors below. How to find a way to fix them?

````
wget http://mirror.esc7.net/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-5.8p1.tar.gz
tar -xvzf openssh-5.8p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-5.8p1
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo make install
useradd git -g git
su git
mkdir .ssh
git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
mkdir -p $HOME/bin
gitolite/install -to $HOME/bin
vi banruosheng.pub
gitolite setup -pk banruosheng.pub
    error:bash: gitolite: command not found
bin/gitolite setup -pk banruosheng.pub
    FATAL: errors found but logfile could not be created
    FATAL: /home/git/.gitolite/logs/gitolite-2013-03.log: 没有那个文件或目录
    FATAL: die  'banruosheng.pub' does not seem to be a valid ssh pubkey file

```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
 error:bash: gitolite: command not found
```

Make sure that `$HOME/bin` is in your `$PATH`.
(See "[How to add a directory to my path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path/60221#60221)")